# How to establish relationship with same entity using JPA, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to create relationships between different persons but couldn't find a way on how to do it using JPA. Below is the model given to support the requirement:

**Person table:**
Id FirstName LastName
1 John          Heller
2 Joseph      Heller
3 Andrew      Heller
4 Steven      Heller
**Person_Relationship table**
Id Person1 Person2 Relationship
1 1             2             Parent
2 2             1             Child
3 1             3             Sibling
4 3             1             Sibling
5 4             1             Secretary
Can someone please share your experience if you have ever implemented the above using Hibernate as JPA provider.

Comment: Have any of these answers helped you? I noticed you have not accepted an answer on any of the 4 questions you have asked. You should acknowledge when someone gives you an answer that helped you out.

Comment: Sorry for that. I am new to stackoverflow. I will do it from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a OneToMany association between a `Person` entity and a `RelationShip` entity, each entity mapping the associated table:

```
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person1")
    private List<RelationShip> relationships;

    public List<Person> getSiblings() {
        List<Person> result = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (RelationShip r : relationShips) {
            if (r.getType() == RelationshipType.SIBLING) {
                result.add(r.getPerson2());
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was able to make it work with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Standard many-to-many relationship using a jointable.

Comment: Given the tables, this is very far from being a standard many-to-many using a join table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Sibling> siblings;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Parent> parents;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Child> children;

    @OneToMany
    Set<Secretary> secretaries;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="person_relationship")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="relationship", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Relationship {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person1")
    private Person owner;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="person2")
    private Person related;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Sibling")
public class Sibling extends Relationship {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Child")
public class Child extends Relationship {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Parent")
public class Parent extends Relationship {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Secretary")
public class Secretary extends Relationship {}
```

Using this will let Hibernate (JPA) do the hard work of discriminating between the different types of relationship.

If only real life were this easy! ;-)